# Can I attach an external GPU to my MacBook Air late 2010?

Tags: macbook-pro, thunderbolt, gpu

I have an old laptop (which is definitely on its last strides). It's a MacBook Air Late 2010 and its running like a slug (I have abused the laptop beyond comprehension) so for its final year or two I want to get the most out of it. I already have a 2' monitor attached and I want to know if I get a GTX 970 and attach it with [one of these things](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B00LTAUTHE) (Using thunderbolt) if it will function properly and that I'm not burning $600 for something my computer can't handle.

Comment: I would check the vendor website, it probably won't work without additional software. But: are you sure it's the graphic card which is slowing down your laptop?

Comment: its not the only thing but im pretty sure it was. i realized today that my computer has display port not thunderbolt but since they look the same i couldn't tell

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately not, [your Macbook](https://support.apple.com/kb/sp618?locale=en_US) doesn't have Thunderbolt, only Mini DisplayPort. For best results, your mac should have Thunderbolt 2 to take full advantage of the speeds.

---

By the way, I have Macbook 2011 and I had 2x Thunderbolt displays at 2560x1440 with my integrated HD3000 512mb without a problem. But it was fast as hell when I added a SATA3 SSD with 560mbps read. Hard drives are bottlenecking! :)

Comment: do you know if i could upgrade the ports to support thunderbolt instead of displayport?

Comment: Nope you can't, you need a newer Macbook. Thunderbolt 1 was released with Early 2011 Macbook and Thunderbolt 2 was released with Late 2013 Macbook.

Comment: so i cant like switch the IO and have it work?